# PySpark unable to Retain VARCHAR length When Reading MSSQL Table to Snowflake

Tags: python, sql-server, database, pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am working on a project where I need to read data from an MSSQL (Microsoft SQL SERVER) table and create a corresponding table in Snowflake using PySpark. The MSSQL table contains columns with specific VARCHAR lengths, and I want to retain these lengths in the corresponding Snowflake table.

However, when I read the MSSQL table using PySpark and write it to Snowflake, the VARCHAR lengths are not retained. Instead, the Snowflake table is created with VARCHAR columns having a length of 16777216 (Max length in Snowflake).

Here's a snippet of the code I'm using:

```
# Reading from MSSQL
df_mssql = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", jdbcUrl) \
    .option("dbtable", "my_table") \
    .options(**mssql_properties) \
    .load()

# Writing to Snowflake
df_mssql.write \
    .format("net.snowflake.spark.snowflake") \
    .options(**snowflake_properties) \
    .mode("overwrite") \
    .save()
```

I've tried various approaches, but I'm unable to find a way to automatically carry over the VARCHAR lengths from the MSSQL table to the Snowflake table. The resulting Snowflake table always has VARCHAR columns with a length of 16777216, regardless of the original lengths in the MSSQL table.

I'm looking for a solution that allows me to retain the original VARCHAR lengths without manually defining the Snowflake table schema or modifying the VARCHAR lengths in the DataFrame.

Any insights or suggestions on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered first creating the table with the desired specification and then **not** using `overwrite` mode? See, for example,  [How to: Load Data in Spark with Overwrite mode without Changing Table Structure](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-Load-Data-in-Spark-with-Overwrite-mode-without-Changing-table-Structure) to see why this matters.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Thank you for sharing. Yes, as a workaround, I'm using the SQLAlchemy library to create the tables automatically, then using the settings in the article you provided to avoid having the table recreated by Spark.